# How to prevent Morphia from storing empty string in MongoDb

Tags: string, mongodb, morphia, is-empty

I am trying to Save a Object to MongoDb using morphia which contains fields that have value as empty string. And I don't want those empty string to be saved in mongoDB.
For Example  : (Json mentioned)I don't want fields like "addressLine2" ,  "postalCd2" to be saved in Mongo.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf8d100fe85543cdc1e3183"),
    "accountNbr" : "test Acct",
    "effectiveDt" : "2019-02-19",
    "entryDt" : "2019-06-06",
    "expirationDt" : "2020-02-19",
    "insuredMailAddress" : {
        "stateCd" : "TestCd",
        "cityNm" : "testCity",
        "addressLine1" : "Test address Line1",
        "addressLine2" : "",
        "postalCd2" : ""
    }
    "streamLineRenewInd" : {
        "code" : " "
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Morphia does not currently support such a feature.  You can, however, filter out the nulls.  You'd just need to make sure your application stores a null instead of "".